# Web browser control detect form submitted?

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

After a user submits a form, how do you detect that the form has been posted/submitted and the browser has navigated to the logged in page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Handle the [`DocumentCompleted`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted.aspx) event and check `e.Url`.